# Paragraph how to get content level wise?

Tags: theming, 8, paragraphs

Using module https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs.

On Admin side I have made content as a 3 level categories. Main Category, Sub Category, Sub Category.

Each category have their content as well.

On twig file when i print

```
{{ content }}
```

It display all data. Which is correct.

I need to fetch individual category & their content & do the styling for each.

How can i retrieve that each field in loop?

[image]

Comment: When you have 3 levels of paragaphs you not only get 3 different paragraph templates, where you can print `{{ content }}`, but also 3 levels of field templates, where you'll find for each field the loop `{% for item in items %}` you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @4k4 I added image in question. Still not get. Can you please explain further? Do u link or reference of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this template file:

*/themes/mytheme/templates/field--paragraph--field-category--faq.html.twig:*

```
    <div{{ attributes }}>
        {% for item in items %}
            <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: So need to overwrite Category Template then Question & Answer Template as well

Comment: Only if you want to change the html markup specific for these fields and/or paragraph types.

Comment: Yes. Need to change HTML only. Have to do in overwrite 3-4 templates. Instead can we get all things in Main File by Loop?